# share specific URL of facebook application

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I am working on an application which consist of questions and answers, i am trying to achieve something:

i have added share button to questions, after sharing and clicking from facebook profile i need to redirect that user to that specific question,

like for example right now tab URL of my app looks like 
https://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_3774862XXXXXX

below the actual url of the question look like

https://myapp.com/index.php?controller=questions&id=20

**** how can i modify my Tab url to pass in share functionality in order to redirect user to a specific URL of application under facebook.

Thanks !